# ASP.NET Core MVC : recursive menu

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I switched from ASP.NET MVC to ASP.NET Core MVC, but how can I run this code in ASP.NET Core MVC. I'm waiting for your help

```
    @helper CreateMenu(IEnumerable<Menuler> anamenu)
{foreach (Menuler rootcat in anamenu.OrderBy(x => x.Sira))
    {
        if (rootcat.AltMenuler.Count() > 0)
        {
            <li>
                <a class="" href="@(rootcat.Url)">
                    @(rootcat.MenuAdi)
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    @CreateSubMenuItems(rootcat)
                </ul>
            </li> }
        else
        {
            <li>
                <a class="" href="@(rootcat.Url)">  @(rootcat.MenuAdi) </a>
            </li>
        }
    }

    @helper CreateSubMenuItems(Menuler menu)
{foreach (Menuler altmenu in menu.AltMenuler.OrderBy(x => x.Sira))
    {
        if (altmenu.AltMenuler.Count() > 0)
        {
            <li>
                <a  href="@(altmenu.Url)">
                    @(altmenu.MenuAdi)
                </a>
                @if (altmenu.AltMenuler.Count() > 0)
                {
                    <ul>
                        @CreateSubMenuItems(altmenu)
                    </ul>}
            </li> }
        else
        {
            <li>
                <a href="@(altmenu.Url)">
                    @(altmenu.MenuAdi)
                </a>
            </li>}
    }

    @CreateMenu(anamenu)
```

Comment: Hi @eyyup, any updates about this case?

Answer (score 0):

The [`@helper` syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/ui-layouts-and-themes/creating-and-using-a-helper-in-an-aspnet-web-pages-site) can help declare/create a reusable helper method in ASP.NET Web Pages (Razor) website, but please note that the `@helper` syntax is not included in ASP.NET Core.

To create a reusable snippets of HTML in ASP.NET Core website, you can try to use partial views/pages, custom taghelpers or view components.

For more information, please check following docs:

- [Partial views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-5.0)
- [Custom tag helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/authoring?view=aspnetcore-5.0)
- [View components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-5.0)